# Views Data Export - Individual records for each file path iteration

Tags: views, importing-exporting

I'm exporting data through Drupal 7 Views 3 data export to CSV file. I've worked out most of the kinks, but cannot find a solution to the following:

CSV file output contains iterations/rows of each node for every image file referenced (3 images for a node = 3 iterations/rows. What I'm aiming for is an image array/list (simple separator) contained in a single node record. I can't see any multiple results options for the field settings and I've got aggregate/group results together selected, but there's no other options (e.g to group by entity ID like for term references)

I'm using a File Usage:File relationship and Field - File: File(Image URL) path to generate the image URLs. I'm aggregating on NID, Image URL among others. I get the feeling the view needs to process the results before it aggregates. Is this the case?

I can export my view if that helps anyone, just say the word.

Many thanks

Comment: I don't think there will be any simple way. Views is just an SQL query builder, and aggregation like this is hard with SQL. Wouldn't it be simpler if you would adapt at the receiving side instead?

Comment: I'm cleaning up in Excel at the moment. Was hoping there would be a more elegant solution, like a structure adjustment etc. -_- Might consider a different output format, like XML or json for better post processing. Does anyone know how good XML/XML software is for comparing/manipulating datasets compared to CSV/Excel?